# Automatically update QLabel text

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application with a simple QLabel. I wondered if it was possible to update automatically its text since the QLabel constructor uses a reference.

```
QLabel ( const QString & text, QWidget * parent = 0, Qt::WindowFlags f = 0 )
```

What I'd like to have is a QLabel whose text is updated when I change the QString contents.

I tried the following code (using Qt 5.0.2) :

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QString str("test");
    QLabel label(str);
    label.setFixedSize(300,70);
    label.show();
    str = "yoh";
    label.repaint();

    return app.exec();
}
```

But the label still shows « test ». So, am I doing something wrong, or is it just not possible to update automatically the content ?

Any help would be appreciated. By the way, there is no problem if I have to subclass QLabel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you can do it. You need to create model.

```
QLabel label;
label.show();

QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(1,1);
QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem(QStringLiteral("test"));
model->setItem(0, 0, item1);
```

Add a mapping between a QLabel and a section from the model, by using [QDataWidgetMapper](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatawidgetmapper.html).

```
QDataWidgetMapper *mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper();
mapper->setModel(model);
mapper->addMapping(&label,0,"text");
mapper->toFirst();
```

Every time the model changes, QLabel is updated with data from the model.

```
model->setData(model->index(0,0),"yoh");
```

Comment: I will consider using a model (didn't know about QDataWidgetMapper), thanks ;)

Comment: That is why I've said about observer pattern which is implemented in mvc pattern and your model connection.

Comment: The `"text"` property in the third parameter of `addMapping` is required due to the open bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10672. Without it, mapping to a `QLabel` will not work. It is not required if you map to a `QLineEdit`.

Comment: @Lucas Where can we find these property names? What is it exactly?

Comment: @ZhangLongQI [Properties](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html) are a QObject class feature that behave like class data members but have additional features accessible through the Meta-Object System such as specifying a getter or a setter. For example, QComboBox has [currentIndex](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#properties), QLabel has [text](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#properties), and QLineEdit has [selectedText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#properties).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. `QtCore` library does not provide binding expressions in C++ code but qt does it in `QtQml` library specially to simplify ui designing. If you are talking about references - you are doing it wrong, and more or less, it is not possible. To update automatically your code should implement a `subscriber` or `observer` software design pattern and your `QLabel` must use it. C++ does not that simple as you might think when you was talking about references.

If you really need a auto-updatable GUI, try `QML`.

Comment: That's why I prefer pointers... :/ Anyway, thanks for the explanation.